# chart.js update is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I'm trying to update my chart but i'm getting this error when i click the button **TypeError: pieChartData.update is not a function**

```
const LatestSales = props => {
      const {pieChartData} = props;


     const toggle = () =>{
      pieChartData.labels[0] = "teste"

      pieChartData.update()
    }


      return (
            <>
                <button onClick={toggle}>toggle</button>
                <Doughnut
                  data={pieChartData}
                  options={pieChartOptions}
                />
            </>
      );
    };
```

what comes from pieChartData: **{labels: Array(3), datasets: Array(1)}**

Comment: what is `pieChartData` and where does it come from? my guess is you are trying to call `.update` on an array, which would throw the error you're getting since arrays don't have a `.update` method

Comment: yes its an array

Comment: if you remove the line `pieChartData.update()`, you won't have an error anymore. what is the behavior you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to change the label name when i press the button, i just did what they show in the docs https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html#updating-options

Comment: i'm assuming `pieChartData` is the state of a parent component here. i believe the best way to do this would be to implement a function that changes the state of `pieChartData` in your parent component. this way, when `pieChartData` changes, `LatestSales` will update upon receiving new props and update your options for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should define a prop in your parent component for setting pie chart data. I assumed its name:   `setPieChartData`

```
   const LatestSales = props => {
     const { setPieChartData, pieChartData} = props;

     const toggle = () =>{
        let $pieChartData = { ...pieChartData };
        $pieChartData.labels[0] = "teste"

        setPieChartData($pieChartData)
     }

     return (
        <>
           <button onClick={toggle}>toggle</button>
              <Doughnut
                 data={pieChartData}
                 options={pieChartOptions}
              />
        </>
     );
   };
```